# How do we call these layouts?

Tags: lightning-experience, multi-select, compact-layout

I am very curious to understand the difference between these two task/log a call layouts. Are they compact layouts? The task layout in the Opportunity detail page allowed me to add multi-picklist field on the layout, while the one for the Account layout did not. Is that possible to add a multi-pick list field on the compact layout? If yes, how can I achieve it.

Please clarify. Given below are the screenshots task/log a call layout on Account and Opportunity detail pages.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are not compact layouts. They are **action layouts**, which may be associated with either global actions or with object-specific actions.

Global Actions are available in Setup. Object-specific actions can be accessed in the Buttons, Links, and Actions section for the associated sObject in Object Manager.

Both types of action can have their associated layout edited, and you can add multi-select picklists to an action layout.